# Formatting Sections of a TextRange or TextRange2 in PowerPoint.Interop C#

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop

I would like to add rich text to a TextBox on a PowerPoint Slide.

I am using .Net `4.7.2` with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint`

## Overview

```
// Initialization of the Application
public PresentationGenerator () {
  pptApplication = new Application ();
}

// Creating a new document based on a teplate.
Presentation pptPresentation = generator.pptApplication.Presentations.Open (templatePath, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, showWindow);


// Setting a slide and editing the text works perfectly fine with this
Slide currentSlide;

currentSlide = pptPresentation.Slides[1];
currentSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Wonderful Title";
currentSlide.Shapes[3].TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Great TextBox";
```

This is an mwe of my setup to set text on slides.

I would however like to add text to one of my shapes using a loop and setting the layout depending on a property.
Imagine the following Array

```
customParagraphs = [
    {
        text:"example heading",
        type:"title"
    },{
        text:"example normal text",
        type:"text"
    }]
```

I can loop over this list and add the text to the end of the `TextRange2` using `.insertAfter(text)` and try setting the font-size for the text portion that i added.

```
TextRange2 textrange = currentSlide.Shapes[3].TextFrame2.TextRange

foreach(var paragraph in customParagraphs){
    TextRange2 paragraphRange = textrange.Paragraphs.insertAfter(paragraph.text)
    if(paragraph.type == "title"){
        paragraphRange.Font.Size = 24.0F;
    }
}
```

This will successfully add the text and change the font-size, if type is title. **However it will change the font-size for the whole text-range!**

The reference returned by `.insertAfter()` seems to refer to the instance of `TextRange2` and not my newly added paragraph.

## My Questions

Is there a way to change the font-size and other attributes of a line, paragraph or word inside a `TextRange` or `TextRange2` element?

Is there a better way to add text to a `TextRange` or `TextRange2` element than `.insertAfter` that preferably returns a reference to only the text i added?

Comment: I would rather use OpenXML sdk. Not just because it is better (and it is better since it does not need power point app to work), but because it has better tools. You can convert pptx to C# code using open xml sdk. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425. Load source pptx and get C# code (Code A). Do the same for desired result. (Code B) Compare code and see what needs to be done to get code B from code A.

Comment: Thank you for your input. In our case we are generating may interconnected shapes on the slides which will become a lot harder if we have to implement it in openXml. We will evaluate that approach.